# How to install Firebird JDBC on Centos

Tags: jdbc, centos, firebird, jaybird

Can anyone help me to install or setup Firebird JDBC on my centos machine. I see no documentation on how to install from their site.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install a JDBC driver. You simply include it in the classpath of your Java application, just like you would do with the jar-file of any other Java library. You then configure (or code) the application to use the driver by specifying the driver name and connection string (or in the case of a `DataSource`: the connection properties).

Documentation for Jaybird can be found on [Firebird: Drivers Documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/drivers-documentation/)

If you need a more specific answer, then please ask a more specific question.